# Randomise Whole Folders

Tags: php, random

I'm in the process of creating an experiment for a psychology researcher, there are various tasks involved which the participant has to complete. I have been asked to randomise the order of the folders, but keep the order of files inside the directories the same.

I have looked at using `glob()` but I think I'm implementing it wrong.

My directory looks like this:

**Clock**

>>*Task 1/Files.*
>>*Task 2/Files.*
>>*Task 3/Files.*

At the moment I have this:

```
    <?php
    function random_folders($dir = 'Clock')
    {
        $folder = glob($dir. '/Task.*');
        $folderRand = array_rand($folder);
        return $folder[$folderRand];
    }
    echo random_folders();
    ?>
```

I've tried googling and using stackoverflow to search for a solution but I can't seem to find one, any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
I should mention that I'm using HTML5, JavaScript, PHP and MySQL to create the website, if that's relevant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `glob()` is a little off. You don't want the `.` before the `*`.  Then use `shuffle()` to shuffle them:

```
function random_folders($dir = 'Clock')
{
    $folder = glob($dir. '/Task*');
    shuffle($folder);
    // Returns the randomized array of folders
    return $folder;
}

$random_folders = random_folders();
// List them and their contents:
foreach ($random_folders as $rf) {
  echo "Folder: $rf\n";
  // List files in ascending order
  $files = scandir($rf, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING);
  foreach ($files as $f) {
    if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
      echo $file . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. However, If I wanted to display contents of the folders, would I do `header("location: ../Clock/$files");`

Comment: @user1656692 What is in the folders? Are they PHP scripts? HTML files? If they are PHP scripts, you could `include($f)` to execute one. If they are HTML files, you would need to `header("location: ../Clock/$f");`

Comment: There are about 40 html files in each folder.